# How to fix: The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task<T> [AppName]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, async-await, repository-pattern

I'm using VS Code and following an ASP.NET Core/ EF Core tutorial and admit I'm not quite clear on how the async, await and Task do (well, I know the first two, but not the third.) I am implementing a repository for the first time, and a UnitofWork Class and Interface to go with it. Here is the UnitofWork Class:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace vega.Persistence
{
  public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
  {
    private readonly VegaDbContext context;

    public UnitOfWork(VegaDbContext context)
    {
      this.context = context;
    }

    public async Task CompleteAsync()
    {
      await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
  }
}
```

In addition to the subject-line error shown by VS-Code intellisense when I hover over the CompleteAsync action name, I get this:

```
'UnitOfWork.CompleteAsync()': not all code paths return a value [AppName]
```

Other perhaps relevant snippets:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace vega.Persistence
{
    public interface IUnitOfWork
    {
        Task CompleteAsync();
    }
}
```

In my Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add Repository and UnitOfWork --scoped (instance persits for life of request),
    // not Transient or Singleton
    services.AddScoped<IVehicleRepository, VehicleRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
}
```

Comment: It's really strange, I don't see anything wrong with your code. Maybe it's a bug with VS Code. Did you try running `dotnet build` in the folder where your project is to see if you get any error message? By the way, writing a unit of work when you're using EF is not very useful, DataContext being already a UnitOfWork implementation. You should write a service if you want to keep the DataContext out of your Controllers.

Comment: Yes. =>
`Build FAILED.

Persistence\UnitOfWork.cs(14,23): error CS1983: The return type of an async method
must be void, Task or Task<T> [C:\Users\..\Vega.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)`

Comment: Also restored project, and restarted VS Code.

Comment: Which version of .NET Core do you use `dotnet --version`? Can you publish your project to GitHub or provide access to it in some other way?

Comment: And the error message is on the `CompleteAsync` method? I just tried copy-pasting your code to a fresh project and can confirm it does build. Did you copy-paste your code from somewhere? I've had sometimes some weird behaviours with "space" characters not being real "space" and the compiler freaking out. Could you try re-typing (without copy pasting) the CompleteAsync method?

Comment: `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.0" />`

https://github.com/patrickgomes1968/vega

Comment: hmm... I DID copy-paste the code -- but only after my own seemingly identical code return the same exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have another `vega.Persistence.Task` type defined in your project. Just add the namespace to correct `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` as return type of your method:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task CompleteAsync()
{
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

And same in your interface.

Comment: Tried this, but got:
`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int>' to 'vega.Persistence.Task' [Vega]`

Comment: Does this imply that the context is 'Persistence' and not my actualy DbContext object?

Comment: Then you just answered your own question. You have 2 classes named Task and your code is probably referencing vega.Persistence.Task instead of System.Threading.Tasks.Task...

Comment: @PatrickGomes, Marco is right. I have updated my answer. I have applied the change and now it compiles.

Comment: Phew! No idea how it got there! It was an empty class. Probably the result of an inadvertant right-click somewhere.

Comment: It's likely because you wrote the class "Task" without adding a Using statement (Or referencing the dependency). The context menu has an option to automatically create a class of that name for you.

Comment: @PatrickGomes, consider to accept answers when they help to solve your questions.