# I am calling a service as below and am getting compile error CS1983 The Return type of an async method must be Task

Tags: c#, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I have the following class:

```
public static class RequestGenerator

{
   
    static string clientID;
    static string clientSecret;

    static string url = "https://servicestierdp1qa.workmgmt-bcbsm/v1.0/createWorkItem";
    static HttpClient client = null;
    static WorkResponse workResponse;
    
    public static string generateRequest(WorkRequest workRequest)
    {
        if (client == null)
        {
            client = new HttpClient();
            clientID = "myclientid";
            clientSecret = "mysecret";

        }
       
        sendRequest(workRequest);  //warning is moot because ensureSuccessStatusCode implicitly awaits
        return workResponse.payloadArea.id;
    }

    static async Task sendRequest(WorkRequest workRequest)
    {


        try
        {

            string jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(workRequest);

            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = client.PostAsync(url,
                                                                new StringContent(jsonRequest,
                                                                Encoding.UTF8,
                                                                "application/json")).Result;
            responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string jsonResponse = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            workResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WorkResponse>(jsonResponse);
            
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

This class is nearly identical to a class from another process that works.  I don't know why I am getting this compile error.

The only real difference between this class and the one that works is the url, clientid and secret  (in addition to names, etc)

Comment: You're calling PostAsync, but rather than `await`ing it you're calling `.Result`? Why?

Comment: You are not awaiting the call to sendRequest so there will not be a response for workResponse yet when the method returns.

Comment: Do you define a type named "Task" in your project? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44055577/how-to-fix-the-return-type-of-an-async-method-must-be-void-task-or-taskt-ap

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix: The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task<T> \[AppName\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44055577/how-to-fix-the-return-type-of-an-async-method-must-be-void-task-or-taskt-ap)

Comment: Yup, I suspect the problem is actually the meaning of the name `Task`. As two side notes though: if you're just going to rethrow exceptions, don't bother with try-catch at all; I'd *strongly* urge you to start following .NET naming conventions ASAP, rather than getting into habits that will be hard to break.

Comment: add await  in your postAsync,  HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsync

Comment: (I'd also return the response from the async method rather than using global state, but again that's a slightly different issue...)

Comment: madreflection's comment nailed my problem:  I have a class named Task.  I will rename it to something that does not cause ambiguity.

Comment: change your `public ` for  `public async Task<string> generateRequest(WorkRequest workRequest)` and add await in `áwait sendRequest(workRequest);`

Comment: This comment is not true: "_warning is moot because ensureSuccessStatusCode implicitly awaits_". I'm not sure what makes you think that, but you definitely should be awaiting `sendRequest(workRequest)`.

Comment: Johnathan Barclay:  Thanks for your response.  The implicit await is directly from Microsoft's documentation and works as expected.

For everybody else:  Thank you for your attention to my issue, but as I stated earlier madReflection nailed the issue.  I changed the name of my 'Task' class and it worked perfectly.  (I could also have used a fully qualified Task  - System.Threading.Task I think)

Comment: I could not find the Microsoft documentation indicating that EnsureSuccessStatusCode impicitly waits, so I ammend to say I read it somewhere and it appears to behave that way.  

It could be that the .Result (at the end of postAsync) impicitly awaits (emulating synchronous execution)  I don't remember exactly why I do it this way (some stack overflow post for sure)